# MySQL timeout only from office network to remote server, but other connections are fine

Tags: mysql

I've been developing these apps just fine on a local machine as has my co worker. We recently moved our work desks so we're now on a different floor of the building, but we only have one router that we're connected to.

Since then, connecting to this one server appears to timeout more often than not. Occasionally I get through, and the loading is instantaneous.

Anyhow we have these connections that were tested

```
1. my computer -> office network -> php pdo      -> mysql server A     - timeout
2. my computer -> office network -> mysql cli    -> mysql server A     - timeout
3. my computer -> office network -> mysql cli    -> mysql server A     - timeout

4. another pc  -> office network -> mysql cli    -> mysql server A     - timeout
5. my computer -> mobile network -> mysql cli    -> mysql server A     - ok

6. my computer -> office network -> ssh server A -> mysql server A     - ok
7. my computer -> office network -> ssh server B -> mysql server A     - ok
8. server B web app              -> php pdo      -> mysql server A     - ok

9.  my computer -> office network -> php pdo     -> mysql server B     - ok
10. my computer -> office network -> mysql cli   -> mysql server B     - ok
```

This has really stumped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your data it seems that you will need the port opened for (mysql cli) server A on the Office network .

Comment: I initially thought that, but wouldn't that also affect Connection #10 which the method is identical, but a different server? As far as I know, they're using the same port number. If there a way to confirm which port is being used on a connection?

Comment: It is most likely the same port for MySQL (3306) but it might only be allowed 1. from your network only to that IP 2. From the server to only allow it from the "mobile network " You can test them with telnet serverA 3306 , telnet serverB 3306 . As a last resort the mysql might use another port (you can see that when you connect to from the mobile network - your connection parameters - port )

Comment: `telnet servera 3306` returns Connection closed by foreign host. `telnet serverb 3306` returns mysql_native_password

Comment: So it is clear that there is a firewall between you and that MySql servera :) , go on the server and allow the connection from your IP (it depends on what OS you are using for servera MySQL ) , then if it is still failing check with the guys hosting the server to allow it , if it is still failing speak with your network admin :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. The issue appears to have been resolved since the router was restarted. That said, I'll see if I can follow your advice to prevent anything similar occurring again.